# Non-unique add() to an many-to-many connection

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Is it possible to add multiple of the same object to the many-to-many connection? The current setup i am running gives me an `Error: Trying to '.add()' an instance which already exists!` everytime i try to add a speaker multiple times. For example, maybe speaker X speaks for 20 min, Speaker Y takes over, and then its speaker X:s turn again. How can i solve this?

this is my event model:

```
attributes: {
   id: {
     type: "integer",
     primaryKey: true,
     autoIncrement: true
   },
   name: {
     type: "string",
     required: true
   },
   speakers: {
     collection: "speaker",
     via: 'events',
     dominant: true
   }
},
addSpeaker: function (options, cb) {
   Event.findOne(options.id).exec(function (err, event) {
     if (err) return cb(err);
     if (!event) return cb(new Error('Event not found.'));
     event.speakers.add(options.speaker);
     event.save(cb);
});
```

And also an Speaker model:

```
attributes: {
name: {
  type: "string",
  required: true
},
title : {
  type: "string"
},
event: {
  model: "event"
},
events: {
  collection: "event",
  via: "speakers"
}
}
```